# Multiple file upload issue in input file

Tags: php, html, jquery, laravel, file-upload

In my `Laravel` project I'm using multiple file upload via `<input type="file">`.

**In my view**:

```
<input type="file" id="upload_requiremnt_files" name="upload_requiremnt_files[]" multiple>
<div id="upload_prev"></div>
```

Above upload tag is inside a form which I'm getting few more data from the user. I submit the form using `AJAX`. From the `AJAX` function I'm passing all the data to the controller.

**`JQuery` function**:

```
        var newFileList = [];
        $(document).ready(function(readyEvent) {
            $('#upload_requiremnt_files').on('change', function(changeEvent) {
                $("#upload_prev").html('');

                var filename = this.value;
                var lastIndex = filename.lastIndexOf("\\");
                if (lastIndex >= 0) {
                    filename = filename.substring(lastIndex + 1);
                }
                var files = changeEvent.target.files;
                for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                    $("#upload_prev").append('<span>' + '<div class="filenameupload" id="'+i+'">' + files[i].name + '<p class="close" ><i class="fa fa-window-close" aria-hidden="true"></i></p></div>' + '</span>');
                }
            });

            $(document).on('click', '.close', function(closeEvent) {
                console.log(closeEvent);
                var id = $(this).parent().attr("id");
                //alert(id);
                console.log(id);
                $(this).parents('span').remove();
                var fileInput = $('#upload_requiremnt_files')[0];

                newFileList = $('#upload_requiremnt_files')[0].files;
                newFileList = Array.prototype.slice.call(newFileList);

                newFileList.splice(id,1);

                fileInput.files = [];
            });
        });
```

Once I select multiple files, those files will be listed down. If I click remove icon for a specific file it will remove. After I click submit even I removed some from those uploaded files all the files will be sent to the controller. But I need to pass only those selected files.

For this matter I have gone through several solutions in stackoverflow also. But couldn't find a better solution for this. Can anyone support me with this? It would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store all your files `initially` in an array using `change` function and then store the remove icon HTML data in another array to match the `fileName` and id we have currently in our main `filesToUpload` array.

If the file name matches with the `fileName` we have currently in the `filesToUpload` we simply splice that item from out main array as well as from `removeFile` array.

To `append` close file `icon` and file `data` we can check the length of our `removeFile` array and then append the data using `.join()` function.

I have added a live counter as well. Which check for file quantity left after removing the files from `filesToUpload` array.

Also, if you will click on `Upload` button you will see the files that you need to send it the `controller` for `processing` as a `formData`.

**Live Demo:** (I have added comments to each line for your reference as well)

```js
$(document).ready(function(readyEvent) {

  var filesToUpload = []; //store files
  var removeFile = []; //remove remove files
  var fileCounter = 0; //count files

  //upload file
  $('#upload_requiremnt_files').on('change', function() {

    $("#upload_prev").html('');

    fileCounter = this.files.length; //count files
    
    //Store all files to our main array
    var files = this.files;
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      filesToUpload.push(files[i]);
    }
    
    //Push file to remove file to that we can match to remove file
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
      removeFile.push('<div class="filenameupload" id="' + i + '"  fileName="' + f.name + '" >' + f.name + '<p class="close" ><i class="fa fa-window-close" aria-hidden="true"></i></p></div>');
    }

    //Append Remove file icon to each file
    if (removeFile.length) {
      $("#upload_prev").html(removeFile.join(""));
    }

    //Show counter
    $('#upload_count').show().text('Total Files To Upload = ' + fileCounter)

  });

  //Remove files 
  $(document).on('click', '.close', function() {

    var i = $(this).parent().attr("id"); //get index
    var fileName = $(this).parent().attr("fileName"); //get fileName

    //Loop through all the file and remove Files
    for (i = 0; i < filesToUpload.length; ++i) {
      if (filesToUpload[i].name == fileName) {
        //Remove the one element at the index where we get a match
        filesToUpload.splice(i, 1);
        removeFile.splice(i, 1);
      }
    }

    //Remove file from DOM
    $(this).parent().remove();

    //Decrease counter
    fileCounter--

    //Update counter
    if (fileCounter > 0) {
      $('#upload_count').text('Total Files To Upload = ' + fileCounter)
    } else {
      $('#upload_count').hide()
    }
  })

  //Demo Upload button
  $(document).on('click', '#upload_file', function() {
    if (filesToUpload.length) {
      alert(filesToUpload.length + ' files will be sent to controller')
    } else {
      alert('Nothing to upload')
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<input type="file" id="upload_requiremnt_files" name="upload_requiremnt_files[]" multiple>
<div id="upload_count"></div>
<div id="upload_prev"></div>
<br>
<button id="upload_file">Upload</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @AlwaysHelping for your solution.

Comment: @GayanS.Muthukumarana You are welcome. Glad that i could helped you. Happy coding